# Visual Studio Debugging Blazor WASM with browserlink active gives 20 seconds timeout

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging Blazor in Visual Studio 2022 (17.5.1) it times out for about 20 seconds when the page i loading the first time or if you reload the page when browserlink is activated.
This makes the browser wait until it can render the page.
If browserlink is disabled the timeout goes down to 12 seconds.

It seems like it has to do with Visual Studios debugging because if I start the webbapp without debugging there is no delay.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get the same behavior with a baseline Blazor Webassembly project created using the Visual Studio template?

Comment: With baseline do you mean a newly created Blazor Web Assembly app? If so. Yes I do get the same behavior. It seems like if it is in .net 6 it does not have this problem but with .net 7 it does.